# Python get unique list items

Tags: python, multithreading, list, multiprocessing

I have a list of dictionaries with millions items, i want to extract only unique items that doesn't have same key name from the list , is there a faster way using threads or something to check in parallel instead sequential, my code as below

Note: my list is list of dictionaries, each dictionary has different keys but they may have the same value of key ['name'], if this matched I should only take one

for example:
lst = [{'name':'x','bar': 1, 'foo': 2}, {'name','z','foo': 3, 'bar': 5}, {'name':x','bar': 33, 'foo': 10}]
 here there are two dictionaries have same name equal x so i will only save one in new list
new_lst  =  [{'name':'x','bar': 1, 'foo': 2}, {'name','z','foo': 3, 'bar': 5}]

```
new_lst  = []
for x in lst:
     flag = False
     for n in new_lst:
          if x['name'] == n['name']:
                  flag = True
                  break
     if not flag:
        new_lst.append(x)
```

Comment: you can use a set for this type of problem : https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: Copy the entries into a dictionary by `name`.

Comment: use [count](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/count)

Comment: which one do you copy when you find the same `key` twice? Will the values always match too?

Comment: count will not work, my list is list of dictionaries, each dictionary has different keys but they may have the same value of key ['name'], if this matched i should only take one

Comment: @Ev.Kounis if two dictionaries in the list have the same value in key ['name'] I will take one only  (doesn't matter which one)

Comment: just flatten the list then. The duplicates will overwrite themselves.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin this is the full code, only left is the list data, I have added example of the list structure

Answer (score 1):

**Reproducible example:**

So I build a reprocible example for a large dict to compute a good benchmark:

```
import string
import random
lst = []
for i in range(10000):
    lst.append({'name':random.choice(string.letters)+random.choice(string.letters),
                'foo':random.choice(range(100)),
                'bar':random.choice(range(100))})
```

**Your way of doing it:**

Then I compile your way in a function:

```
def your_fun(lst):
    new_lst  = []
    for x in lst:
         flag = False
         for n in new_lst:
              if x['name'] == n['name']:
                      flag = True
                      break
         if not flag:
            new_lst.append(x)
    return(new_lst)
```

**A faster way:**

A faster way it to limitate the number of loops (loops are slows) by storing names you have already seen in a list.

```
def my_fun(lst):
    new_lst  = []
    seens_names = []
    for x in lst:
         if not x['name'] in seens_names:
            new_lst.append(x)
            seens_names.append(x['name'])
    return(new_lst)
```

**Benchmarks:**

And I perform benchmarks:

```
%timeit your_fun(lst)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.14 s per loop


%timeit my_fun(lst)
10 loops, best of 3: 143 ms per loop
```

So just by supressing one loop, it is possible to divide time cost by 10...

**Conclusion:**

Before considering multithreading, avoid as much as possible loops it will make your code faster.

There might be some other way to keep improving performance.

Another improvement before looking into multithreading would be to code this task in cython.

Comment: thanks you, I tested your method it is much faster than mine, I also found below method to be the fastest, by using dict instead of list for seen names

new_dct = {}
for i,x in enumerate(lst):
    if not new_dct.get(x['name']):
        new_dct[x['name']] = x

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide an example, it is hard to accurately capture what you want, but you might find the following interesting:

```
a = [{'bar': 1, 'foo': 2}, {'foobar': 3, 'bar': 5}]

a = {k: v for subdict in a for k, v in subdict.items()}
print(a)  # {'bar': 5, 'foo': 2, 'foobar': 3}
#            ^ 'bar' appears only once (but value could be either 1 or 5)
#                      ^ 'foobar' is taken from the 1st dict. Does not exist in 2nd.
#                                 ^ 'foo' is taken from the 2nd dict. Does not exist in 1st.
```

What I am proposing here is the *flattening* of your `list` and reducing it to a single `dict`. The duplicates will overwrite themselves (order cannot be guaranteed) automatically.

---

Alternatively, you could achieve the same with the following (which is simpler to understand):

```
res = a[0]
for d in a[1:]:
    res.update(d)  # every dict is <<applied>> to the previous one as an update.
print(res)  # {'bar': 5, 'foo': 2, 'foobar': 3}
```

---

---

**NOTE**

My solutions above assume that you do not care about preserving the `dict`-in-`list` schema.

Comment: list is like below 
a = [{'name':'x','bar': 1, 'foo': 2}, {'name','z','foobar': 3, 'bar': 5}, {'name':x','bar': 33, 'foo': 10}]
i don't want to merge dictionaries, here there are two dictionaries have same name equal x so i will only save one in new list
new_lst  =  [{'name':'x','bar': 1, 'foo': 2}, {'name','z','foobar': 3, 'bar': 5}]